# Using AWS Powershell to deploy to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to deploy onto Elastic Beanstalk using AWS Powershell.

Currently I am just trying to get the EB environment using the following cmdlet:
 + Get-EBEnvironment
      -ApplicationName 
      -EnvironmentId 
      -VersionLabel 
      -EnvironmentName 
      -IncludedDeletedBackTo 
      -IncludeDeleted

This is the cmdlet I used:  Get-EBEnvironment -ApplicationName appName

However, I am getting the following error:

Get-EBEnvironment : No region specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
At C:\Users\lowong\Desktop\script.ps1:22 char:1

- Get-EBEnvironment -ApplicationName evcfacade
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...vironmentCmdlet:GetEBEnvironmentCmdlet) [Get-EBEnvironment], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EB.GetEBEnvironmentCmdlet

Am I missing other fields I have to put onto the cmdlet? or what's the problem?

(Here's the link to the documentation of the cmdlet: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=New-EBApplicationVersion.html&tocid=New-EBApplicationVersion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error mentions the following:

> No region specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.

So, you have 2 possible resolutions:

1. Include the `-Region` parameter, such as `-Region us-east-1`. See [Get-EBEnvironment Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=New-EBApplicationVersion.html&tocid=New-EBApplicationVersion). Or
2. Use the `Set-DefaultAWSRegion` cmdlet to set the default region. See [Set-DefaultAWSRegion Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Set-DefaultAWSRegion.html&tocid=Set-DefaultAWSRegion)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the problem! I didn't think region really met setting the default region. I thought something was wrong with the command.

Comment: Your second link goes to the wrong location.  It goes to New-EBApplicationVersion.

Comment: Thanks. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `Set-DefaultAWSRegion` is not persisted (you have to specify it for every powershell session).

If you want to persist region, it can be done as part of setting up your credentials with:

```
Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName {profileName} -Region {region}
```

For more information see: [Specifying Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html#specifying-your-aws-credentials-use/)